# Azure Monitor Query client library - The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation (InsufficientAccessError)

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, defaultazurecredential

in order to programmatically retrive some **AppTraces** and **AppExceptions** info from an Azure **Application Insights** Logs resource, we followed the instructions included in the following article advicing to adopt the new **Azure Monitor Query** client library for .NET to fulfill the purpose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Monitor.Query-readme?view=azure-dotnet

Strictly following the above article instructions (and using the **DefaultAzureCredential** object to authenticate), we managed to get the client library's **LogsQueryClient** object working fine in the local version of the developed web api (ASP .NET Core 6.0). And so, locally we are eable to fetch the logs info we need.
But once we published the web api on the Cloud (under the same Azure subscription of the Application Insights target resource) we started to get the following error:

- **Message**: The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation
- **Status**: 403 (Forbidden)
- **ErrorCode**: InsufficientAccessError

**N.B.**
Surprisingly we didn't find any thread explaining, step by step how to fix the problem with specific reference to the new Azure Monitor Query client library.

To fix the issue, we tried replacing the class **DefaultAzureCredential** with the class **ClientSecretCredential** generating and assigning it a new client secret.

Here are the details concerning the steps we followed to implement the ClientSecretCredentials.
In particular, we have:

1. Setup a new **Azure AD Application**.
2. Assigned it the required permissions ==> **Data.Read** (Read Log Analytics data -  Granted from Admin).
3. Assinged to the Registered App (AAD Application) the **Reader Role** from the Application Insights Resource's Access control (IAM) section of the Azure Portal.
4. Created a new **client secret** for the AAD Application.
5. Created a new Azure **Web API**, on witch we Installed the **Azure Monitor Query** client library for .NET.
6. To retrive Logs data, we programmatically istantiated a new **Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential** object, assigning it the right tenantId, the client (application) ID of the AAD Application and the client secret previously generated for the App Registration.
7. In the Program.cs file of the web api we created a singleton instance of the class **LogsQueryClient** assigning it the above **ClientSecretCredential** object.
8. And finally we invoked the **QueryWorkspaceAsync** method of the class LogsQueryClient, passing it the **WorkSpaceId** of the Application Insights Resource (whom logs have to be read) and the query to retrive.

Unfortunately, replacing the class DefaultAzureCredential with ClientSecretCredential didn't work and the error message keeps to be the same.

**N.B.**

- The **AAD User Type** of the user who: developed and released the web api, registered the new Azure AD Application and granted it the necessary permissions is "**Member**".
- The above user, refers to the same tenant id as the resources he managed in the above steps (Web Api, AAD Application etc).
- During the release process of the web api, a new API Management service was specifically created by the same user releasing the app.

Here are the code snippets:

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{
    static LogsQueryClient func(LogsQueryClientOptions options)
    {
        options.Retry.Mode = Azure.Core.RetryMode.Exponential;
        options.Retry.MaxRetries = 5;
        var csc = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        return new LogsQueryClient(csc, options);
    }
    builder.AddClient<LogsQueryClient, LogsQueryClientOptions>(func);
    var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    builder.UseCredential(credentials);
});
```

**Controller.cs**    (get **logsQueryClient** through dependency injection)

```
Response<LogsQueryResult> response = await logsQueryClient.QueryWorkspaceAsync(workSpaceId, query);
```

Comment: can you please share the exact error message for this am trying to catch such scenarios and would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your appreciated help.
We finally managed to spot where the problem was.

After the point 3 listed in our original post:
<<Assign to the Registered App (AAD Application) the "**Reader Role**" for the Application Insights acting from the resource's Access control (IAM) section of the Azure Portal.>>

... We omitted to do the same thing for the **Log Analytics workspace**.
Each Application Insight resource refers infact to a specific Workspace.
For that reason, it is necessary to assign the same reader role to the Registered App also for the above workspace.
Log Analytics workspaces too have infact an **Access control (IAM)** section in the Azure Portal, just like the other resources.

Assigning this role to the AAD registered app the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation

The error clearly shows that it doesn't have a sufficient access to process the request.

To identify the new RBAC permission, Azure App Insights REST API takes an hour to sync with AAD and it throws **Status 403** as error code without complete sync. Refer [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview#api-key-authentication-for-sample-data) for related stuff

Basically, this error can happen when the user doesn't have access to authorize Access token with AAD

1. Provide the required access to the user which you want to authorize.
2. Make sure to check your request are valid before processing your APi request in Production Environment. (Token, GUID, etc.,).