# How can a user run Query Pack items on Application Insights using PowerShell?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-powershell, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

Using the steps below, one can run a Kusto query stored in a [`Default Query Pack`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability-blog/log-analytics-query-packs/ba-p/2314721) from PowerShell on a `Log Analytics Workspace`.

```
$baseUrl  = "https://management.azure.com"
$RId      = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName LogAnalyticsDefaultResources -Name DefaultQueryPack).ResourceId
$token    = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl $baseUrl).Token
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$baseUrl$RId/queries?api-version=2019-09-01" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}

$response.value.properties.displayname  # Display names
#Runs the first query in the pack
Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -Query ($response.value)[0].properties.body -WorkspaceId <>
```

How should a user run a query from the Default pack on `Application Insights` [connected to the `Log Analytics Workspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#migrate-your-resource) using [Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/invoke-azoperationalinsightsquery)? I get `Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'` while running an AppInsights query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting one's classic AppInsights resource and connecting it with a Log Analytics Workspace one can update one's AppInsights queries based on the new table structure.

[Migrate an Application Insights classic resource to a workspace-based resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#table-structure)

Once the AppInsights query is updated to use the new table structure, one can save them to the Default query pack and use the same method to execute it from PowerShell.

For Example: The AppInsights query `pageViews| take 10` would become `AppPageViews| take 10`.

Answer (score 0):

> How should one run a query from the Default pack on `Application Insights`  connected to the  `Log Analytics Workspace`using Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery?

You can use `Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery` to run queries on Log Analytics workspace like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId 'b83c1ed3'
$rith_workspaceId = "3c62e221"
$rith_query = @"
AzureMetrics
"@

Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -WorkspaceId $rith_workspaceId  -Query $rith_query
```

[image]

And the above `Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery` only works on Log Analytics workspaces and its tables and does not work on Application Insights and its tables.

Above in place Azure Metrics, you can use the query that you have got from output of  `($response.value)[-1].properties.body`

[image]

If you want to run query on application insights you can follow this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990632/powershell-script-to-retrieve-logs-from-applications-insights). the value of `$query` can be assigned to  (`$response.value)[0].properties.body`. You can also use [cli command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/app-insights?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-app-insights-query-examples)  .

Comment: Why isn't there an equivalent of this [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/app-insights?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-app-insights-query-examples) in the [AppInsights module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/?view=azps-11.1.0)? Why won't `Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery` work if [AppInsights is connected to the LAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#migrate-your-resource)?

Comment: Even if app insights is connected, its a different service from log analytics workspace, it is two different services, there is no similar command in PowerShell, I would suggest you to raise a support request in Azure Portal for that.

Comment: The [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74993337/2748772) only works for an AppId, not for a user. The legacy API for Application Insights is available at api.applicationinsights.io, but that endpoint is being replaced by api.loganalytics.azure.com. And Application Insights API Keys are deprecated and will be retired in March 2026.

Comment: Yes, User needs APP ID then only one can access, If deprecated new versions will be released or command will get updated, one should change the codes according to updated versions.